# Vector Calculus Divergence

Tags: vector-analysis

> Prove that $$\nabla.\left(\vec{r}\,\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)\right)= \frac3{r^4}.$$

My doubt is that here should we consider  the term 
$\vec{r}$ and $\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$ as the ones to be multiplied or as dot product?
Also please give the solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of attaching a link or typing out formulas.

Comment: Also, please show your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: This is probably a typo, the $\vec r$ should not be a vector. Try to show that $\nabla\cdot \left(r \nabla(1/r^3)\right) = 3/r^4$.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla\big(\frac{1}{r^3}\big) = \frac{-3}{r^4}\nabla(r) = \frac{-3}{r^5}\vec{r} $

$\bigg[r^2 = x^2 +y^2 + z^2$

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$, similarly for y and z.

$\nabla r = \Sigma(\hat i \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}) = \frac{1}{r}\Sigma(x \hat i) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}\bigg] $

$y = \nabla.\bigg( r.\nabla\big(\frac{1}{r^3}\big)\bigg) = \nabla.\bigg( r.\frac{-3}{r^5}\vec{r}\bigg) = -3\nabla.\bigg( \frac{\vec{r}}{r^4}\bigg) = -3\bigg[\frac{1}{r^4}\nabla.\bigg( \vec{r}\bigg) + \vec{r}.\nabla(\frac{1}{r^4})\bigg]$

$y =-3\bigg[\frac{1}{r^4}3 + \vec{r}.\frac{-4}{r^6}\vec{r}\bigg] = -3\bigg[\frac{1}{r^4}3 + {r^2}\frac{-4}{r^6}\bigg] = \frac{3}{r^4}  $

[Formulae used: $grad(r) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \ , \ div(\vec{r}) = 3 \ , \ \vec{r}.\vec{r} = r^2 $]